# Ошибка при сравнение изображений OpenCv (не могу найти баг в коде)

Tags: c++, изображения, opencv, сравнение

Так, с помощью OpenCv и функции absdiff пытаюсь вычесть матрицы одинаковых(в смысле размер/тип) матриц, чтобы узнать отличаются ли изображения...
Мы делаем скриншот текущего изображения на экране и пытаемся определить отличается ли часть изображения(через Rect) от части основного изображения, если отличается, то ничего не происходит, если одинаковы, то делаем клик мышкой, но изображение всегда отличается от другого, притом что картинки одинаковые, не подскажите, где в коде проблема которую я не заметил?  (код работает, но некорректно)

```
        screenshot(); // функция делающая скриншот экрана
        Mat imageNow = imread("D:\\Arry\\react\\pressreact2.png", IMREAD_COLOR); // Основное изображение
        Mat imageCHECK = imread("D:\\Arry\\react\\pressreactCHECK.png", IMREAD_COLOR); // изображение с которым сравниваем
        Rect Rec(920, 620, 10, 10); // выделяем прямоугольник x,y длина, ширина
        Rect Res(920, 620, 10, 10); 
        rectangle(imageNow, Rec, Scalar(255), 1, 8, 0); // рисуем прямоугольник
        rectangle(imageCHECK, Res, Scalar(255), 1, 8, 0);
        Mat image_osn = imageNow(Rec);     // создаём основные матрицы
        Mat image_check_end = imageCHECK(Res);
       


        Mat result;                                        // матрица для результата
        absdiff(image_osn, image_check_end, result);       // вычитаем матрицы и записываем в result

        cvtColor(image_osn, image_osn, COLOR_RGB2GRAY, 1); // приводим изображения к одной цветовой палитре
        cvtColor(image_check_end, image_check_end, COLOR_RGB2GRAY, 1);
        cvtColor(result, result, COLOR_RGB2GRAY, 1);

        if (countNonZero(result) == 0) // если не отличается то:
        {
            click();         // функция клика левой кнопкой мыши
            std::cout << "\a";
        }
        else
        {
           
        }
```

Comment: Сравниваете png? Есть вероятность что проблема в этом. Возможно при сжатии изображения, каждый раз это происходит немножко по-разному (это не точно, в качестве предположения).

Comment: Если вы делаете скриншот, то зачем промежуточно его сохранять (сжимать в архив), а затем читать (извлекать)? Сравнивайте bitmap'ы.

Comment: О, нет, программа должна реагировать на изменение изображения с задержкой +-20мс, сравнение попиксельно будет слишком долгим.
А вот насчёт png...
Только что обнаружил что размеры двух одинаковых картинок слегка разнятся, значит в коде скриншота напортачил, буду исправлять.

Comment: Сравнение произойдёт довольно быстро. Уж точно быстрее компрессии и декомпрессии png. А как вы ещё планируете сравнивать изображения, если не попиксельно? Сперва нужно сравнить ширину и высоту, затем глубину (в битах, байтах, или лучше сравнивать сам формат, вроде RGB888), и только после сравнивать вектор пикселей. Логическое И становиться ложным, как только встретиться первое ложное условие, т.е. до сравнения векторов может и не дойти.